# Form duplication jQuery validation wont work on duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know quiet where im going wrong, but i have a form that needs to duplicate. so far it duplicates but i have a validation on the field "ID", and it only works on the first from and none of the duplicates.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Heres the code:

jQuery:

```
    //Clone Tracking
var g_counter = 1;
var d_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
//Clone Tracking
//General Variables
var name_input_groups = ["name-group-1"];
var surname_input_groups = ["surname-group-1"];
var input_groups = ["group-1"];
var age_input_groups = ["age-group-1"];
var gender_input_groups = ["gender-group-1"];
var town_input_groups = ["town-group-1"];
var cell_input_groups = ["cell-group-1"];
var pass_input_groups = ["pass-group-1"];
var relation_input_groups = ["relation-group-1"];
//General Variables
//Generate variables
var name_fields=[0];
var surname_fields=[0];
var id_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var passport_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13];
var cell_fields = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var age_fields=[0];
var gender_fields=[0];
var town_fields=[0];
var relation_fields=[0];

var name_input = "<input class='name' />";
var surname_input = "<input class='surname' />";
var id_input = "<input class='id' maxlength='1' />";
var age_input = "<input class='age' />";
var gender_input = "<input class='gender' maxlength='1' />";
var town_input = "<input class='town' />";
var cell_input = "<input class='cell' maxlength='1' />";
var pass_input = "<input class='pass' maxlength='1' />";
var relation_input ="<input type='checkbox' class='spouse' />" + 
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='ownchild' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='adopted' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='stepchild' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='parent' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='inlaw' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='brother' />" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' class='other' />";
//Generate variables
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    //populate jquery generated fields
    jQuery(surname_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(surname_input).appendTo('#surname-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(name_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(name_input).appendTo('#name-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(id_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(id_input).appendTo('#group-1');
    });
    jQuery(age_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(age_input).appendTo('#age-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(gender_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(gender_input).appendTo('#gender-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(town_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(town_input).appendTo('#town-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(cell_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(cell_input).appendTo('#cell-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(passport_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(pass_input).appendTo('#pass-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(relation_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(relation_input).appendTo('#relation-group-1');
    });
    //populate jquery generated fields
    //Cloning Function
    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        // Store the value of the previous Id to insert the cloned div..
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;

        // Clone the Dependant Div and set a new id
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', 'dependant-'+g_counter);
        var cell_newDiv = 'cell-group-'+ g_counter;
        var town_newDiv = 'town-group-'+ g_counter;
        var gender_newDiv = 'gender-group-'+ g_counter;
        var age_newDiv = 'age-group-'+ g_counter;
        var pass_newDiv = 'pass-group-'+ g_counter;
        var id_newDiv = 'group-'+ g_counter;
        var name_newDiv = 'name-group-'+ g_counter;
        var surname_newDiv = 'surname-group-'+ g_counter;
        var relation_newDiv = 'relation-group-'+ g_counter;

        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"#name-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#surname-group-1').attr('id',"#surname-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"#group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#age-group-1').attr('id',"#age-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#gender-group-1').attr('id',"#gender-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#town-group-1').attr('id',"#town-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#cell-group-1').attr('id',"#cell-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#pass-group-1').attr('id',"#pass-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#relation-group-1').attr('id',"#relation-group-" + g_counter );

        // You don't need to Loop thru the inputs to set the value
        $clonedDiv.find('input').val('');

        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);

        name_input_groups.push(name_newDiv);
        surname_input_groups.push(surname_newDiv);
        cell_input_groups.push(cell_newDiv);
        age_input_groups.push(age_newDiv);
        gender_input_groups.push(gender_newDiv);
        town_input_groups.push(town_newDiv);
        pass_input_groups.push(pass_newDiv);
        relation_input_groups.push(relation_newDiv);
        input_groups.push(id_newDiv);
    };
    //Cloning Function
    //Validation


    function validate_gen() {};

    function validate_Id(values) {
            var idNumber = values;
            var correct = true;
            if (idNumber.length != 13 || !isNumber(idNumber)) {correct = false;}
            var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));
            var today = new Date();
            var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
            var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
            var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();
            var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
            var age = Math.floor((today-tempDate) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var fullDate = id_date + "-" + (id_month + 1) + "-" + id_year;
            if (!((tempDate.getYear() == idNumber.substring(0, 2)) && (id_month == idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1) && (id_date == idNumber.substring(4, 6)))) {
correct = false;}
            var genderCode = idNumber.substring(6, 10);
            var gender = parseInt(genderCode) < 5000 ? "Female" : "Male";
            var citzenship = parseInt(idNumber.substring(10, 11)) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No";
            var tempTotal = 0;
            var checkSum = 0;
            var multiplier = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {tempTotal = parseInt(idNumber.charAt(i)) * multiplier;
                if (tempTotal > 9) {tempTotal = parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(0)) + parseInt(tempTotal.toString().charAt(1));}
                checkSum = checkSum + tempTotal;
                multiplier = (multiplier % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;}
            if ((checkSum % 10) != 0) {correct = false;};
            if (correct) {
                 $.each(age_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = age_input_groups[i];
                    var values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(age);
                    });
                });
               $.each(gender_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = gender_input_groups[i];
                    var values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val(gender);
                    });
                });
                console.log(idNumber);
            }
            else {
                console.log(idNumber + "-wrong");
            }
            return false;}

        function isNumber(n) {return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);};

    function validate_Pass(pass_values) {
        console.log("passport"+pass_values);
    };

    function validate_Email() {};

    function validate_Cell(cell_values) {
        if (cell_values != 10){
            console.log("Cell= "+cell_values);
        }else{
            console.log("bad");
        }
    };
    //Validation
//Multiple Inputs function
//ID
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.id', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
            //Validate(current);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.id', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.id').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = input_groups[i];
                    var values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Id(values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//ID
//CELL
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.cell', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
            //Validate(current);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.cell', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.cell').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(cell_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = cell_input_groups[i];
                    var cell_values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Cell(cell_values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//CELL
//Pasport
    //Multiple Inputs function
        $(document).on('keydown', 'input.pass', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).prev().val('');
            $(this).prev().focus();
            //Validate(current);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.pass', function() {
        if (this.value.match(/\d+/)) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.next('input.pass').length) {
                $this.next().focus();
            } else {
                $.each(pass_input_groups , function(i){
                    var id = pass_input_groups[i];
                    var pass_values = $.map($('#'+id + ' input') , function(e,i){
                        return $(e).val();
                    }).join('');
                    validate_Pass(pass_values);
                });
            }
        }
    });
//Pasport
    //Multiple Inputs function
});
```

and heres the HTML:

```
<div id="dependant-1">
    name<div id="name-group-1"></div>
    surname<div id="surname-group-1"></div>
    id<div id="group-1"></div>
    age<div id="age-group-1"></div>
    gender<div id="gender-group-1"></div>
    townofbirth<div id="town-group-1"></div>
    cell<div id="cell-group-1"></div>
    passport<div id="pass-group-1"></div>
    relationship<div id="relation-group-1"></div>
</div>

<button id="clone">clone</button>
```

also here's a sample South African id number:
8509295266086

and the jsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/GdGen/

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates, you have multiple forms with the same ID?

Comment: well see when you clone the current form, it duplicates the fields. therefore if you look at the validation, it works off the class "id"... But im probably wrong.. cause ts not working.. so any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was fairly tricky to track down but quite easy to fix.

In the `clone_dependant` function, code like this is used to modify the `ID` of the given element:

```
$clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"#group-" + g_counter );
```

The problem is that you don't need to use the `#` character in the ID. This line would then become:

```
$clonedDiv.find('#group-1').attr('id',"group-" + g_counter );
```

where the validation worked as it should (so you'll need to look at doing this for the other elements that have their IDs modified).

Using the first approach, I found that I was unable to find any of the newly added elements. E.g., running `console.log($("#group-" + g_counter).length);` in the `clone_dependant` function directly after `$clonedDiv` was added to the DOM would output 0.

Answer (score 0):

A Possible answer would be to run the validation for each form separately:

I can see that the  and  both contain a form and each needs to be validated. I would give each "dependant" div created a class of dependant and then you can do:

```
$('.dependant').each(function(k, v){

      $(v).find('.name').val(); // is the parent div, you can access the child elements this way


});
```

It would be less prone to error in a loop